# How can i point to another pointer then increment the first one's value without changing the second's value

Tags: c, list, pointers, while-loop

How can i iterate over the list using X without actually changing list->tete value

```
celluleS* rechercherC(listeS *list,int val){

celluleS *X = list->tete;
celluleS *Y = NULL;

while(X != NULL && X->s != NULL && val != X->s->value ){
    Y = X;
    X = X->succ;
}


return Y;
}
```

Comment: You want tho iterate over a chain-list without changing the head of the list address value?

Comment: Where exaxctly do you change `list->tete` value?

Answer (score 0):

At no point in your code are you changing the `list->tete` value.

`*X = list->tete` means X is a pointer to the head of the list

your assignments `Y = X;` and `X = X->succ;` do not change the values that X and Y are pointed to nor does it change any property of the list.

If the `list->tete` value is changing, you are changing the value elsewhere in your code.